# Query parent document using two filter clauses

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr and I want to query a parent document using two constraints. It is currently working for just one contraint.

Example:

```
q={!parent which=type:parent}child_field:something
```

But I want to get parent documents that are defined as a parent (type attribute = "parent") AND have some specific word in field "name".

I've tried the following, but it returns an error:

```
q={!parent which=(type:parent) AND (name:someone)}child_field:something
```

> org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Expected identifier at pos 33 str='{!parent which=(type:parent) AND (name:someone)}child_field:something'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the recommendation under the [BlockJoinParentQueryParser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-BlockJoinParentQueryParser):

> Using which
> A common mistake is to try to filter parents with a which filter, as in this bad example:
>
> `q={!parent which="title:join"}comments:SolrCloud`
>
> Instead, you should use a sibling mandatory clause as a filter:
>
> `q=+title:join +{!parent which="content_type:parentDocument"}comments:SolrCloud`

So deriving from that example, giving the required filter as the first mandatory clause should work:

```
q=+name:someone +{!parent which="type:parent"}child_field:something
```

Comment: if i need to search with two values in child field then, how to write the query. ie i need both child_field:val-1 and child_field:val-2

Comment: @AshokSri Please ask a new question if you have a different question and include the proper details.